Command I used a while ago to help me with terrain edit being able to span things using just how far, wide and tall
I had a command I used to use and stopped playing for a few days. I forgot it and can't find the video. With the command, you could input how tall/width/height instead of x/y/z and it would spawn whatever I set it as without coordinates! Does anyone know what it is?

This is an exact duplicate of your previously closed question. Please don't repost it, and instead edit that question to add any relevant details you can think of.

@Skye-AT As that question has no answers, it probably can't

@TreeSpawned Good point, but it's a boilerplate comment. See this Meta thread, as well.

I didn't think my account would post that. This question had a vote when I casted the vote for duplicate(otherwise I would have casted to "needs clarity" option). Strange...

The /fill command is best for spawning blocks in a specific area. Although it doesn’t allow you to input dimensions directly, it lets you define a rectangular region by specifying two opposite corners. Here’s how you can use it:
/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block>

Where:
   are the coordinates of the first corner of the area to fill.
   are the coordinates of the opposite corner.
 is the type of block you want to fill the area with.
Suppose you want to fill a 10x10x10 area with stone from your current position (~ ~ ~):
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~9 ~9 ~9 stone

This command will fill the area starting from your current position (~ ~ ~) to a point 10 blocks in each direction (~10 ~10 ~10) with stone. You need to go 9 blocks away from the starting point, making the total 10 blocks per dimension.
Note: To fill an area of size NxNxN, you should go N-1 blocks away from your starting point to get the correct dimensions. Because "~" represents your current position.
To create a solid cube of diamond blocks from (0, 0, 0) to (5, 5, 5), you’d use:
/fill 0 0 0 5 5 5 minecraft:diamond_block

The /fill command also has additional options for more control:
replace: Replace only specific blocks.
hollow: Create a hollow structure.
outline: Create only the outline of the structure.
For example, to create a hollow 5x5x5 cube from your current position:
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~4 ~4 ~4 hollow

If you want to set the world spawn point (where players initially appear), you can use the /setworldspawn command. This won’t directly spawn blocks, but it affects where new players will appear. For example:
/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>

